# Vedis: извлечь все данные

Tags: python, nosql, vedis

Всем добрый день, использую Vedis для хранения данных телеграм-бота, подскажите, открываю через контекстный менеджер

```
with Vedis(file) as db:
```

Возможно ли вытащить из него все данные, не обращаясь по конкретному ключу?

Answer (score 0):

```
with Vedis(file) as db:
    all_values = list(db.values())
```

В `all_values` вы получите список всех значений.

Comment: У меня такого метода нет :С
Vedis версии 0.7.1
Python 3.7